# Show Heroku database information in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Is there a way to display a database's information in a Django view?

For example, I know in the Heroku cli you can do `heroku pg:info -a your_app` to view the database's table count, row count, type, etc.

Is there a way to get this same information in Django to make it viewable in a template to keep track of storage, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following function to get the row count of the current database:

```
from django.db import connections

def db_row_count():
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    query = """
        SELECT sum(reltuples)
        FROM pg_class
        WHERE relname
        IN (
            SELECT c.relname
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
            ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
            WHERE c.relkind = 'r'
            AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
            AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
            AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
            AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
        );
        """
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return int(row[0])
```